# How to add an infinite number of images to the html5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to let a user drag and drop as many images as they wish onto an html5 canvas. From tutorials online I gather its something like:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    context = canvas.getContext("2d"),

    imgs = arr.map(function callback(currentValue, index, array) {
        img = img = document.createElement("img");
    }[, thisArg])
    mouseDown = false,
    brushColor = "rgb(0, 0, 0)",
    hasText = true,
    clearCanvas = function () {
        if (hasText) {
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            hasText = false;
        }
    };

for (var i=0;i<imgs.length;i++){
    imgs[i].addEventListener("load",function(){
        context.drawImage(img,0,0);
    })
}
```

I know line 4 is completely wrong..., but usually people seem to create their images as variables and then change the source with the dragged image. Since I want as many images as the user wishes to add, that would be an array without any size?

Furthermore, Since this code gets called once, on page load, this array cannot be appended to later (like when the user decides to add another image). So maybe this entire paradigm is incorrect in this case?

Can someone advise me on how to go about this? Thanks!

EDIT:

proposed solution:

```
imgs_arr = [];
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    imgs = imgs_arr.map(function callback(src) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = src;
        return img;
    });
    mouseDown = false,
    brushColor = "rgb(0, 0, 0)",
    hasText = true,
    clearCanvas = function () {
        if (hasText) {
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            hasText = false;
        }
    };

// Adding instructions
context.fillText("Drop an image onto the canvas", 240, 200);
context.fillText("Click a spot to set as brush color", 240, 220);

function drawImage(element,index,array){
    element.addEventListener("load",function(){
        clearCanvas()
        context.drawImage(element,0,0)
    })
}
imgs_arr.forEach(drawImage);
```

Currently throws : `Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null(anonymous function)` because my imgs_arr is blank - no one has added images yet.

Comment: JavaScript arrays don't require a size parameter and automatically expand when new things are added.  That said, I'm pretty sure your browser would crash well before you hit infinity.

Comment: BigBoy1337 said " *this question is specifically about images in the html5 canvas. I feel like this doesn't apply here? Correct me if Im wrong*  " Sorry I must have miss read the question, I thought you wanted to load an unlimited number of images as an array. I have removed the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `arr` is an array of image URLs, your map should look like this:

```
imgs = arr.map(function callback(src) {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = src;
  return img;
});
```

I renamed `currentValue` to `src` to make sense as to what it is, and I removed the extra parameters, but that was all technically optional.

The important parts are:

- Create a new `img` element and assign it to a variable.
- Assign the URL to the `src` of that `img.
- Return the image.

The `map()` function gathers up all the values returned from the callback and turns those into an array. That'll give you an array of `Image` objects (which are the JS form of the HTML `<img>` element).

The rest looks more or less correct (though you really should use `;` instead of `,` for ending your lines to avoid possible weird things).

Also, for adding more after it is initialized, you should just have to `push()` a new `Image` onto the array and then redraw it.

Comment: I see. I am then confused on how to create the arr list of images? For instance, before anyone adds anything, the array would be empty right? This seems to cause problems (see added EDIT)

Comment: Your code doesn't even show `appendChild()`, so  you have something else going on somewhere. You shouldn't need to call `appendChild()` for this program at all. You aren't appending the images anywhere, they just stay in memory. With the code you have showing, an empty array shouldn't cause an issue, it just wouldn't draw anything.